# How Strings are compared in Rust?

Tags: rust

If I do this:

```rs
let a = String::from("hello world");
let b = String::from("hello world");
if a == b {
    println!("Equal!");
}
```

The code will print out "Equal!".
But how does it exactly compare them? Does String have defined a method for comparing, or does this comparison somehow convert them to `str`-s, or what else?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want to know which function ends up being called (and how it gets there) or if you're asking how said function would be implemented.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html

Comment: @Stargateur does string have this?

Comment: @Matthieu M. does this print "equal" because there's a function for comparison defined on String, or for another reason?

Comment: [`String` impls `PartialEq<String>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2068-2077).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: That's... an answer, or the beginning of one if you also want to explain what `==` desugars to and what `Eq` is about.

Comment: @MatthieuM. `Eq` is not related here. And that's why I linked  a duplicate.